# SQL query, search data and return project name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

Hey I'm looking for some help in creating a stored procedure.
Here are the details
I have a table called `Partners` which holds the `partner information (Columns, PartnerID and partnername)` I also have another table called `ProjectPartners` which holds the link between the project and the partners `columns( PPID, Partner1, partner2, partner3....partner25)` and I have a further table called `ProjectDetails` which holds the information on the project `columns( ProjectDID, Project)` The foreign key for `projectpartners` is within `Projectdetails`.

I'm looking to create a stored procedure that allows me to enter a `partner name`, this then displays the projects they are included within. I already have some mock code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@partnername nvarchar(50)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT ProjectDID, Project
FROM Projectdetails
WHERE Partners.PartnerName = @partnername
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The classic design for this type of thing is that your `ProjectPartner` table should have the ProjectID and a single PartnerID, then with several partners associated with the project you have several ProjectPartner rows. This would make your query MUCH easier. That's why it's the classic solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the joins through your table schema to get the necessary data.
Take a read of this MSDN article about [joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select ProjectDetails.ProjectDID, ProjectDetails.Project
from ProjectDetails
join ProjectPartners on ProjectPartners.ProjectDID = ProjectDetails.ProjectDID
join Partners on Partners.PartnerId  = ProjectPartners.PPID
where Partners.PartnerName = @partnerName
```

You haven't described the relationship between `ProjectPartners` and `Partner`, so I am assuming that the `PPID` column on `ProjectPartners` is the relationship

You have also mentioned that your `ProjectPartners` table has the columns `PPID, Partner1, partner2, partner3....partner25`. Are you only planning on having 25 partners. If you have 26 will you add a new column? You might want to address that.

Also in column naming conventions, some are a bit muddled.
You have `PPID` on `ProjectPartners`. I presume this means `ProjectPartnersId`.
On the table `ProjectDetails` you have the column `ProjectDID`.
This is slightly inconsistent. I guess it should either be `PDID` on `ProjectDetails` or `ProjectPID` on ProjectPartners
Personally, I have always had always had a preference for plain old `Id` as my Identity column.

### UPDATE:

Based on your comments below, it sounds like you might have something a little fundamental wrong with your tables:

```
create table Partners (
    Id int not null primary key identity,
    PartnerName nvarchar(100) not null)
go

create table ProjectDetails(
    Id int not null primary key identity,
    Project nvarchar(100) not null)
go


create table ProjectPartners (
PartnersId int not null,
    ProjectDetailsId int not null
)
go

alter table ProjectPartners add constraint FK_ProjectPartners_PartnersId_Partners_Id foreign key (PartnersId) references Partners(Id)
alter table ProjectPartners add constraint FK_ProjectPartners_ProjectDetailsId_ProjectDetails_Id foreign key (ProjectDetailsId) references ProjectDetails(Id)
go
```

I would suggest changing your database schema to one that is a bit more flexible as per the one provided above.
This will prevent the ever growing `ProjectPartners` table by adding a new column each time you have a new partner.

It will fix all issues with your foreign keys and make your tables a bit more intuitive.

This would now yield the SQL:

```
select ProjectDetails.Project, ProjectDetails.Id
from ProjectDetails
join ProjectPartners on ProjectPartners.ProjectDetailsId = ProjectDetails.Id
join Partners on Partners.Id = ProjectPartners.PartnersId
where Partners.PartnerName= @partnerName
```

Comment: They're linked using the Partners table
Primary Key PartnerID
and within the projectPartners table
Foreign key is (Partner1, Partner2...partner 25)